# Fragment in a tab layout is blank after pressing back button

Tags: android

I have a navhost where fragments are swapped in and out and inside the navhost is a tabLayout with 3 fragments in the 3 tabs. once I go from the contact fragment to the addContact fragment and press the back button, the contact fragment is blank, the other 2 fragments are also blank but after a short delay, the view will load for them but not the contact fragment. this video will show what I'm saying a bit better https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fQlzTWV04Su-Gdi98buTbq4PIYKhSj7u/view?usp=sharing.

I've seen other people have this problem but they are using fragment transaction whereas I'm using a nav graph for navigation

my Fragment with the tablayout (activity_message.xml)

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Fragments.MainMenuFragment">


<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
        android:padding="@dimen/appbar_padding"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" /></androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

my contact fragment (contact_fragment.xml)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Fragments.contactFragment">


<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" /></androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

my add contact fragment

```
public class AddContactFragment extends Fragment {
private Contact contact;

public AddContactFragment() {

}

public static AddContactFragment newInstance(){
    AddContactFragment fragment = new AddContactFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    //args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    //args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed() {
            Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(R.id.action_addContactFragment_to_mainMenuFragment);
        }
    };
    requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_contact_fragment,container,false);
    TextView nameHeading = view.findViewById(R.id.contactNameHeading);
    TextView numberHeading = view.findViewById(R.id.contactNoHeading);
    TextView idHeading = view.findViewById(R.id.contactIdHeading);
    nameHeading.setText("Name");
    numberHeading.setText("Phone Number");
    numberHeading.setText("Account ID");
    return view;
    }
}
```

my contact fragment (one in the tab layout)

```
public class contactFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
private ArrayList<Contact> contacts;
// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

public contactFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment contactFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static contactFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    contactFragment fragment = new contactFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    final View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact, container, false);
    RecyclerView rvContacts = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    contacts = Contact.createContactsList(50);
    ContactsAdapter adapter = new ContactsAdapter(contacts);
    rvContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
    rvContacts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    FloatingActionButton fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_mainMenuFragment_to_addContactFragment);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
}
```

my main menu fragment

```
public class MainMenuFragment extends Fragment {

public MainMenuFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
public static MainMenuFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    MainMenuFragment fragment = new MainMenuFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_message,container,false);

    SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this.getContext(), getFragmentManager());
    ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabs = view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    return view;
}
}
```

my navhost (acvtivity_message_nav.xml)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MessageActivity"
>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_message" /></androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

my message activity

```
public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_nav);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
        finish();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

my navgraph

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph_message"
app:startDestination="@id/mainMenuFragment">


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/addContactFragment"
    android:name="com.example.encryptedsmsapp.Fragments.AddContactFragment"
    android:label="AddContactFragment" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_addContactFragment_to_mainMenuFragment"
        app:destination="@id/mainMenuFragment" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/contactFragment"
    android:name="com.example.encryptedsmsapp.Fragments.contactFragment"
    android:label="fragment_contact"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_contact" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_contactFragment_to_addContactFragment"
        app:destination="@id/addContactFragment" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mainMenuFragment"
    android:name="com.example.encryptedsmsapp.Fragments.MainMenuFragment"
    android:label="activity_message"
    tools:layout="@layout/activity_message" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_mainMenuFragment_to_addContactFragment"
        app:destination="@id/addContactFragment" />
</fragment>
```

Comment: This is expected behavior since when you navigate to a destination fragment, your previous fragment's lifecycle will be destroyed. If you want to preserve those data you need to save the data in a `ViewModel` or `SavedInstance` bundle. Note: The solution is not a one-way line answer you need to deal with configuration change & surviving it so that itself is a big problem to solve.

Comment: thanks for the feedback but i discovered something else that was causing the problem, thanks anyway

Comment: What was the problem? If you managed to solve it, a self answer would be nice for the community